# Calcular prazos que não seja nos fins de semana

Tags: php

Terei um sistema que terá um **prazo de dias** Ex: 30 dias.

Preciso calcular uma data dado um determinado prazo, que caso seja fim de semana ela seja interpretada como o último dia útil dentro do prazo.

**Exemplo:**

**Hoje:** 09-12-2014,
**Prazo:** 11 dias

Deveria cair no dia **20-12-2014**(sábado), porem o sistema deve identificar e reduzir o prazo para 10 dias e informar a data final para o prazo que será **19-12-2014**.

Comment: Não é a resposta completa mas já é um rumo pra seguir :`echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+5 days', strtotime('14-07-2014')));` soma 5 dias a partir da data de '14-07-2014' para fazer a partir de hoje `echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+5 days'));`

Comment: Por exemplo: $data = hoje; tenho que verificar se($data menos 1dia) é sabado/domingo ou tenho que verificar se $data é sabado/domingo?

Comment: Se a data final é sábado ou domingo tenho que fazer com que ele "dê como prazo final" a sexta feira por ser dia útil.

Comment: Você precisa então que dado um prazo de por exemplo 30 dias, contando a partir de hoje, que informe a data final, dado que se o dia final for um sabado ou domingo, ela seja alterada para sexta? Não consegui entender direito o que precisa.

Comment: Estou vendo algo assim: $dias = 30; // Ex de entrada
$dataFinal = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $dias . " day", strtotime("now"))); // Aqui eu vou conseguir a data pra final + 30 com isso acho que da pra começar. Pois vou inserir no banco a data de Hoje e também essa tada final e ai faço um diff do SQL pra tentar mostrar pro usuário tempo de dias que falta. A questão agora é final de semana.

Comment: Sobre final de semana vamos ver exemplo: Sendo a data de hoje 09/12/2014 e mais 11 dias vai cair no dia 20/12/2014 ou seja, sábado! Com isso para eu dizer para usuário que o dia limite para ele resolver ISSO, vai ser dia 19/12/2014 por sábado não será dia útil. Sacou? :D

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19334/discussion-between-antony-alkmim-and-phpricardo).

Answer (score 1):

Esse metodo calcula umm prazo para que um prazo prévio não seja um sábado ou domingo.

```
function calcularPrazo($prazoPrevio){
    $dataSTR = date('d-m-Y'); //hoje

    $data = explode('-',$dataSTR);

    //time do dia que sera o dia final do prazo previo
    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $data[1], intval($data[0]) + $prazoPrevio, $data[2]);

    $diaSemana = date("w", $time);

    switch($diaSemana){
        case 0: //domingo
            //subtrair mais dois dias
            $prazoPrevio -= 2;
            break;
        case 6: //sabado
            //subtrair mais um dias
            $prazoPrevio -= 1;
            break;
    }

    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $data[1], intval($data[0]) + $prazoPrevio, $data[2]);
    return date('d-m-Y',$time);
}
echo calcularPrazo(11);
```

Exemplo funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/LJ7bx8)

Comment: Função está funcionando bem, agora um futuro implemento nela de como ficaria na questão dos feriados na semana?

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada e tentar implementar nesse método.

Comment: Feriados fica complicado, por que tem feriados como o carnaval que não tem dias específicos, todo ano são datas diferentes.